# Register and call query in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to register query (like the percolate process) and call them by name to execute them.
I am building an application that will let the user save search query associated with a label. I would like to save the query generated by the filter in ES.

If I save the query in an index, I have to call ES first to retrieve the query, extract the field containing the query and then call ES again to execute it. Can I do it in one call ?

The other solution is to register queries (labels with _percolator with an identifier of the user:
/_percolate/transaction/user1_label1

```
{
  "userId": "user1",
  "query":{
     "term":{"field1":"foo" }
   }
}
```

and when there is a new document use the percolator in a non indexing mode (filtered per userId) to retrieve which query match, and then update the document by adding a field  "label":["user1_label1", "user1_label2"] and finaly index the document. SO the labelling is done at indexing time.

What do you think ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many saved search queries are we talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Filter Aliases.](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-aliases.html)

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_aliases' -d '
{
    "actions" : [
         {
            "add" : {
                 "index" : "the_real_index",
                 "alias" : "user1",
                 "filter" : { "term" : { "field1" : "foo" } }
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

Comment: Just be careful if you have too many saved search queries. Aliases are kept in memory all the time and the master node maintains them as part of cluster state.